# How to segment two objects in a picture using opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

How to segment two objects in a picture using `opencv`?

Suggestions and code snippets in either C++ or python are much appreciated.

In the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj1ZQ.jpg), the monkey holds the tree so there is some overlap section. The question is how to segment monkey and tree or just erase the tree.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a lot harder than it looks, and it is difficult to solve using a code 'snippet'.

The first step is to remove the background. The background has a fairly even color, so this won't be hard. You can check the pixel values and set them to zero when they have a color that is similar to the background color.

You will then have to segment different regions (those surrounded by edges). This is not hard because the edges are fairly sharp and have a single color.

The last step, which is hard, is to combine remaining regions into two different objects. You will need to use some prior knowledge about each object (monkey and tree, in this case).

You can start by looking at opencv tutorials for beginners and trying to perform the first two steps. The results and the code you used can be posted here, so that many of us can help from there on.